# Treewidth related properties of a bipartite graph with bounded local crossing number and diameter

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

If a bipartite degree at most $3$ graph on $O(n^2)$ vertices with diameter at most $O(\log n)$ has property that every edge intersects at most $O(\log n)$ edges on a planar drawing then does any of the following have $O(n^\alpha)$ upper bound at a fixed $\alpha\in(0,1)$:

1. Genus
2. Treewidth
3. Cliquewidth?